# passing 3 arrays in foreach

Tags: java, php, android, arrays

In java code i have this

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> al = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

for (int i = 0; i < alitems.size(); i++) {

    al.add(new BasicNameValuePair("items[]", alitems.get(i)));
    al.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty[]", alnoof.get(i)));
    al.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price[]", alprice.get(i)));
}
```

Note: here  alitems, alnoof, alprice are ArrayLists

**php code**

```
foreach (array_combine($_POST['items'], $_POST['qty']) as $val => $no) {

   $v = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
   $va = mysql_real_escape_string($no);
}
```

now i am able to get 2 array values of $v and $va but I am not able to get the price arraylist. How to do it?

```
suppose $_POST['items']={pencil,pen,watch}
        $_POST['qty']={2,3,4}
        $_POST['price']={20,30,40}
```

i need to insert values in database as :

```
pencil,2,20   pen,3,30   watch,4,40
```

Kindly help me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP also has `for` loop

```
$_POST['items'] = ["pencil","pen","watch"];
$_POST['qty'] = [2,3,4];
$_POST['price'] = [20,30,40];

for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['items']); $i ++) {
    echo $_POST['items'][$i], " ", $_POST['qty'][$i], " ", $_POST['price'][$i], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Or

```
foreach ( array_map(null, $_POST['items'], $_POST['qty'], $_POST['price']) as $var ) {
    list($item, $qty, $price) = $var;
    echo $item, " ", $qty, " ", $price, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Please not that `[]` is only supported in PHP >= `5.4` other whise you have to use `array()`